# IBM Management Center for Websphere Commerce: does anyone know why would products randomly change the visibility status and how to prevent it?

Tags: websphere, visibility, commerce, websphere-commerce

I've noticed that random items tend to show up on the website when they shouldn't. The visibility box is not being checked, but for some reason it changes its status randomly. Does anyone know what might be the cause of this issue and how to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your product have a "Announcement Date".

You can check that:

> - Edit a product
> - Go to the "Manage Product" tab.
> - Deploy "Publishing" menu
> - Check the date of "Announcement date".

If the date is tomorrow, you product should be published tomorrow.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd submit a PMR to IBM Software Support.   They'll ask you to enable the catalog logs and it'll tell you why.   I think @Dekx got it right but there are also marketing rules that may be changing the position of the items.